# Image handling in backbone and node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, amazon-s3

I have some issues understanding image data transfer. Form one side I have backbone, on the other side I have Node and must be able to save images on S3 AWS.

I was thinking to use Ajax to save images on S3. Idea is to save image location in database and serve it with the model. Browser will simply load the image from S3.

1. If I use Ajax, I will use POST?
2. When I get that POST on node.js... the image will be in req.body??? If it is in req.body in what format it is? Base64?
3. If it is in req.body... what do I do with it. There are detailed documents for S3-AWS for node.js, and I will read them in detail.

But please can someone kill this fog that I have regarding image transfers?

Answer (score 1):

The files are coming in `req.files`, not in `req.body`. I'll suggest to check [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) part of the express's documentation. You still need the `bodyParser` middleware, but what you get is not a binary data. It is a temp file which you can copy, read or move. Here is a good material on the subject http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

OK, I always panick, but in essence it is simple.

And yes, POST is used. NOt it does not make big difference how is the upload handled, either by AJAX or simply by form way, one submit to handle them all.

In any case, I can suggest [this place](http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-and-resizing-an-image-using-node-js/#comment-4531). It was joy reading it.